# Axios - Workfront API - Create folder

Tags: node.js, axios, attask, workfront-api

Workfront API version: 9.0

I need to create a folder for a particular project.  The following request works fine in Postman.

```
curl --location --request POST 'https://company.my.workfront.com/attask/api/v9.0/docfdr' \
--header 'sessionId: my-session-id' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--header 'Cookie: wf-cookie' \
--data-raw '{
  "name": "Folder name",
  "projectID": "project-id"
}'
```

But when trying to replicate it using Axios, I get:

```
{ 
  message: 'APIModel V9_0 does not support field projectId (DocumentFolder)' 
}
```

This is pretty much my code:

```
async createFolder(foldername, projectId) {
  // sessionId header is previously globally setup
  // using axios.defaults.headers.common.sessionID = 'sessionId';
  try {
    await axios.post(
      'https://company.my.workfront.com/attask/api/v9.0/docfdr',
      {
        name: foldername,
        projectId: projectId
      }
    );
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error.response.data.error)
  }
}
```

Comment: In your js code you have `projectId` which I guess should be `projectID` ?

Comment: Oh man! You saved my life. Thanks a lot! I was completely blind.